# Retrieving a field from a sequelize query result returns undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I wrote a sequelize query to retrieve users data together with their maximum kyc level.
It worked but for some weird reason I can't access certain fields in the query result.

The sequelize query:

```
    const users = await models["account"].findAll({
      subQuery: false,
      where: params.search && {
        [Op.or]: [
          { first_name: { [Op.like]: `%${params.search}%` } },
          { last_name: { [Op.like]: `%${params.search}%` } },
          { email: { [Op.like]: `%${params.search}%` } },
        ],
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: models["kyc_verification"],
          as: "kyc_verifications",
          include: [
            {
              model: models["kyc_verification_level"],
              as: "kyc_verification_level",
            },
          ],
          attributes: [
            [models.sequelize.fn("COUNT", "*"), "count"],
            [
              models.sequelize.fn(
                "MAX",
                models.sequelize.col(
                  "kyc_verifications.kyc_verification_level.index"
                )
              ),
              "maxLevel",
            ],
          ],
        },
      ],

      group: ["account.id"],
      having: params.level && {
        "kyc_verifications.maxLevel": params.level,
      },
      order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
      limit: 100,
      offset,
    });

    return users[0].kyc_verifications[0].count;
```

The format of the data received is as follows:

```
  {
    "first_name": "Precious",
    "kyc_verifications": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "maxLevel": 2,
        "kyc_verification_level": {
          "id": "e1fa491d-7d78-4f7e-abf3-2aa38aa2470b",
          "name": "Level 1",
          "index": 1,
          "requirements": "[\"phone_number\"]",
          "limits": "{\"daily\":0,\"weekly\":0,\"monthly\":0}",
          "status": "active",
          "created_at": "2023-03-13T11:25:34.000Z",
          "updated_at": "2023-03-13T11:25:34.000Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I try to retrieve the data containing the count as follows, i get a result:

```
return users[0].kyc_verifications[0];
```

but when i try to retriee the count field as follows:

```
 return users[0].kyc_verifications[0].count;
```

I get undefined

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(users[0].kyc_verifications[0])` and see what you got

Comment: @Konrad Thank you, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users))[0].kyc_verifications[0]
some how worked.